# Trouble identifying concurrency in Threaded Loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm having an hard time understanding the concurrency here and where to place exclusion locks.

The ideia is to create one thread for each server the client knows. Servers are not known on compile time. A client as View of servers that change over time. Each thread (who talks to a server via remote call) is placed on the taskArray which is later returned to the calling function, where a WaitAll, WaitAny among other types of Wait are done over it depending on many factors.

The problem is that, when I have N servers, say three. All three tasks make the call to the 3rd server, sometimes the 2nd server on the replicasList.

If I place the Sleep code, in the For loop, everything behaves as expected, regardless of how many servers I'm running. However, hard coding stuff like this is never a good ideia and I'm looking for someone who can explain exactly what's going on here (I have my suspicions) or at least what variables I should lock. Because the ones I've tryed locking before applying the sleep, didn't fix the problem.

The code where I create each task is this one:

```
    private Task<ReplyData>[] InitiateServerCalls(List<ServerData> replicasList, XuLiskovRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        int replicasCount = replicasList.Count;
        ServerData serverData;
        RequestData requestData;
        Task<ReplyData>[] tasksArray = new Task<ReplyData>[replicasCount];

        try
        {
            for (int ridx = 0; ridx < replicasCount; ridx++)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(250);
                serverData = replicasList[ridx];
                requestData = request.RequestData;
                tasksArray[ridx] = new Task<ReplyData>(() => CallServer(serverData, requestData, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
                tasksArray[ridx].Start();
            }
        }
        catch (RemotingException) { RequestViewChange(); }

        return tasksArray;
    }
```

The method each Thread should run is the following:

```
     private ReplyData CallServer(ServerData serverData, RequestData requestData, CancellationToken token)
    {
        string serverProxyURL;
        IServerService server_proxy;

        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        serverProxyURL = $"tcp://{serverData.ServerURL}/{serverData.ServerId}";
        Utils.Print($" [*] Asking {serverData.ServerId} to execute request...");
        server_proxy = (IServerService)Activator.GetObject(typeof(IServerService), serverProxyURL);

        return server_proxy.Request(requestData);
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you move the declaration of `ServerData serverData;` and `RequestData requestData` into the lines that are setting the data. I think they are getting closured into the lamda of your Task with the wrong values.

Comment: That was exactly the problem.

Doing no pre-declaration fixed the problem on all tests I created on hundrends of calls;

Comment: I promoted that comment to an answer after testing on my end also.

Comment: *DON'T* use cold tasks. They aren't threads. Calling `.Start()` doesn't guarantee the task will start immediatelly any more that `Task.Run` does. Use Task.Run when you want something to run in the background instead of creating a cold task and calling `.Start()`.

Comment: Why `Thread.Sleep`? Is this an attempt to throttle requests?

Comment: I'm no longer using the Sleep, after doing what Nathan recommended!
Before following his recommendation, this Sleep was the only thing that made my requests run the other variable changed. I will look into the Run method. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `serverData` and `requestDat` are getting closured into the lamda of your Task with the wrong values. Moving the declaration of the variables into the loop should alleviate this

```
private Task<ReplyData>[] InitiateServerCalls(List<ServerData> replicasList, XuLiskovRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    int replicasCount = replicasList.Count;
    Task<ReplyData>[] tasksArray = new Task<ReplyData>[replicasCount];

    try
    {
        for (int ridx = 0; ridx < replicasCount; ridx++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(250);
            ServerData serverData = replicasList[ridx];
            RequestData requestData = request.RequestData;
            tasksArray[ridx] = new Task<ReplyData>(() => CallServer(serverData, requestData, cancellationToken), cancellationToken);
            tasksArray[ridx].Start();
        }
    }
    catch (RemotingException) { RequestViewChange(); }

    return tasksArray;
}
```

Comment: Good pick up. This is one reason why the old practice of declaring all variables at the start of a method should be knocked on the head once-and-for-all.

Comment: Hi @Francisco Barros if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution  There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation. Says I need 15reputations for my Vote to be made public. That's why I did the next best thing, put it bold on the top. :)
Edit: Never mind.